# Websocket connection not working using NGINX with SSL instead its working fine using direct ip address with port

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, ssl, websocket

```
upstream nodes {
    ip_hash; 
    server 127.0.0.1:3004;
}
server {
    root /var/www/sub.example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name sub.example.com www.sub.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
        
    # Proxy API requests to the API server
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3004;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
    # Proxy WebSocket requests to the socket server
    location /socket {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3004;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    } 
        
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;  # Adjust as per yo>
    }
    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pe>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.sub.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = sub.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub.example.com www.sub.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

const socket = io('http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3004');
this above connection works well

const socket = io('wss://sub.example.com/socket');
but this isnt working neither i am seeing any error on console just got disconnection callback in few seconds constantly. Can you suggest me what i am doing wrong?